# How to have modal work when image tag is inside figure tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a modal to show up on my image gallery but when the images are inside figure tags (which I need for my hover effect) the modal stops working.

I think that it is something to do with the figure tag but I think I've been looking at it so long I'm stumped!

Modal code by itself and working is:
https://jsfiddle.net/ctrant/vz8qyj7r/5/

```
<img class="galleryImg" id="img-0" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/1" alt="Alt Text 1">
<img class="galleryImg" id="img-1" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/2" alt="Alt Text 2">
```

My code I'd like it to work in is:
https://jsfiddle.net/ctrant/9jkd4px0/14/

```
<div class="gallery-item people">
      <figure class="effect-milo">
        <img class="galleryImg" id="img-0" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/5" alt="img01"/>
        <figcaption>
          <h2>Faithful <span>Milo</span></h2>
          <p>Milo went to the woods. He took a fun ride and never came back.</p>
          <!-- <a href="#">View more</a> -->
        </figcaption>     
      </figure>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-item people">
      <figure class="effect-milo">
        <img class="galleryImg" id="img-1" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/4" alt="img02"/>
        <figcaption>
          <h2>Faithful <span>Milo</span></h2>
          <p>Milo went to the woods. He took a fun ride and never came back.</p>
          <!-- <a href="#">View more</a> -->
        </figcaption>     
      </figure>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your fig caption covers your image so you either need to bind the click event to the fig caption and then find the image in relation to the fig caption or make it so the caption does not cover the image so you can click the image

Comment: Thanks Pete, I knew it was something simple tripping me up!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried pointer events? https://jsfiddle.net/wwWaldi/j10e8bdr/5/

```
figure figcaption{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

beware of browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility

Comment: My pleasure. :D